Identifying Causes of Apartment Occupancy Changes for a Single Property (Including Average Market Data)
I am conducting a statistical analysis to determine the causes of a change in apartment complex occupancy over the last 5 quarters. I have the following data:
My property:



Quarter
Occupancy Rate
Property Average Asking Rent
Property Average Asking Rent Per Square Foot
Total Number of Units
Average Square Feet Per Unit
Ad Spend Per Lease




2023 Q1
93%
1320.30
1.52
300
870
175.9323


2023 Q2
92%
1323.88
1.52
300
870
206.6253


2023 Q3
89%
1302.44
1.50
300
870
243.9502


2024 Q4
91%
1298.36
1.49
300
870
290.6671


2024 Q1
94%
1369.59
1.57
300
870
393.1836



*I do have daily and monthly data for these variables as well, but for the sake of comparison I broke them out by quarter
Market:



Quarter
Occupancy Rate
Market Average Asking Rent
Market Average Asking Rent Per Square Foot
Total Number of Units
Average Square Feet Per Unit




2023 Q1
91%
1453.51
1.60
183690
908.4438324


2023 Q2
90%
1436.13
1.58
185399
908.9414186


2023 Q3
89%
1433.91
1.58
187042
907.5410094


2024 Q4
90%
1454.16
1.60
188619
908.8524628


2024 Q1
90%
1458.78
1.60
189603
911.738739



What statistical methods would be best to identify whether our rent adjustments, changes in ad spend, or broader market trends are driving changes in occupancy? Specifically, I'm considering approaches like regression analysis or time-series analysis but am unsure how to structure the analysis given the mixed data (individual vs. market averages).
Initial thoughts/concerns:

Is quarterly data useful enough or at all? Rents are tied to leasing trends and market changes (by nature very reactive), so I worry that a quarterly time-scale will make it difficult to see whether occupancy is affected by rent changes or rent changes are affected by occupancy. This also raises concerns for me about independence. Unfortunately, I only have access to quarterly data for the market, and only averages (not property specific).
I've thought of transforming the data so that we have the quarter over quarter change in rent, occupancy, etc., but I'm not sure if that's helpful in this case.

I graduated with a degree in applied statistics a few years ago, but I'm very rusty and looking to get back up to speed in general (not just for this one problem); any guidance regarding resources would be appreciated.
Thank you!
